# cmd shell flashes across in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Today, I took a crake at vs code and I've written a simple Cpp program.Here it is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

When I pressed F5 to compile and run, the cmd shell just flashed across...The means the program was terminated automatically...
I hope that the shell would terminate only after I press any key to continue, just like compiled in Dev C++, what should I do?DO I need to add something in the tasks.json or the launch.json?

```
{//tasks.json
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "args": ["-g","${file}","-o","${file}.exe"],    
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
}


{//launch.json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",                
            "type": "cppdbg",                          
            "request": "launch",                        
            //"launchOptionType": "Local",               
            "targetArchitecture": "x86",                
            "program": "${file}.exe",                   
            "miDebuggerPath":"d:\\C++\\Dev c++\\DevCpp\\32\\MinGW32\\bin\\gdb.exe", 
            "args": ["blackkitty",  "1221", "# #"],     
            "stopAtEntry": false,                      
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",                  
            "externalConsole": true,                    
            "preLaunchTask": "g++"　　                  
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @RawN l tried but it doesn't work 

Comment: My bad, I thought you were launching console application from Visual Studio.

Comment: Please avoid tagging both C and C++ unless your question involves both languages.  They are not the same, so it would be appreciated if you could [edit] the question to remove any irrelevant tags.

Comment: fine，I will pay  attention next time